# how to get same fields from jsonArray

Tags: java, json, parsing

using gson, I parsed data in json format and now I need to extract the value "dt_txt" and their value "temp" from this data and I don’t understand how to pull and paste them into the collection where the key is "dt_txt" and its value is "temp "
The data that I received: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGCKI.jpg

```
package testClassPackage;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class weatherParse {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String sURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/?q=Odessa,ua&APPID=518a64dd48106aa542464d3bd94d12ce"; //just a string

        // Connect to the URL using java's native library
        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        JsonArray message = rootobj.get("list").getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < message.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you upload the sample JSON not as image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iterate over the JsonArray(message I changed to messages here) as JsonElement and get main object from the element then fetch th corresponding temp.

```
   Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();

    for(JsonElement lst : messages) {
        JsonObject lstObject = lst.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject el = (JsonObject) lstObject.get("main");
        System.out.println(lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString()  +" "+el.get("temp").getAsString());
        data.put(lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString(), el.get("temp").getAsString()); 
    }
```